# Invalid align attribute HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a table cell with an `align` attibute, like this:

```
<td style="border-right: #1c2872 1px solid; border-top: #1c2872 1px solid; border-left: #1c2872 1px solid; border-bottom: #1c2872 1px solid" 
    align="middle"  
    width="95"  
    bgColor="#fafad2">
        <!-- Content here ... -->
</td>
```

But I get this strange error:

> The 'align' attribute is invalid - The value 'middle' is invalid according to its datatype 'Union' - The value 'middle' is not valid according to any of the memberTypes of the union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Vertical Alignment

Use the [`valign` HTML attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp) or the `vertical-align` CSS attribute. This attribute can be one of `top|middle|bottom|baseline`.

### Horizontal (Text-) Alignment

Use the [`align` HTML attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp) or the `text-align` CSS attribute. This attribute (for TD) can be one of `left|right|center|justify|char`.

Comment: Quoting the linked articles: _"The align [and valign] attribute[s] of <td> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."_

Answer (score 2):

It should be `align="center"`

Align middle is for vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

The align tag for a TD can only include these parameters:

1. left
2. right
3. center
4. justify
5. char

So, if you want to center the text, you might use `center`.